# How could I apply a proper event handling or even event delegation to my example code?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-delegation

I am trying to use the same function to change the color of three different divs, but it does not work. Please see below the code below:

```
const hours=document.getElementById('hours');
const minutes=document.getElementById('minutes');
const seconds=document.getElementById('seconds');

hours.addEventListener('click',changeColor);
minutes.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
seconds.addEventListener('click', changeColor);

function changeColor(obj){
        if(obj.style.backgroundColor==='seashell'){
            obj.style.backgroundColor='red';
        } else{
            obj.style.backgroundColor='seashell';
        }
    }
```

Comment: btw the technique being used is plain direct event handling. [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) differs from the former. ... [David Walsh :: How JavaScript Event Delegation Works](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) ... [javascript.info :: Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) ... [jQuery :: Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [handler function (callback)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback) of a registered [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#syntax) gets passed an [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#properties) object. If one wants to access the element where the listener has been registered at then one should use the `event`'s [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) property and not [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) since the latter must not be identical to the former.

The OP's ***event handling*** example ...

```js
function changeColor(evt) {
  const obj = evt.currentTarget;
  const objStyle = obj.style;

  const bgColor = (objStyle.backgroundColor === 'seashell')
    ? 'red'
    : 'seashell';

  objStyle.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
document
  .querySelectorAll('[type="number"]')
  .forEach(elmNode =>
    elmNode.addEventListener('click' ,changeColor)
  );
```

```html
<input id="hours" type="number" min="0" max="23" />
<input id="minutes" type="number" min="0" max="59" />
<input id="seconds" type="number" min="0" max="59" />
```

... turned into an ***event delegation*** based example ...

```js
function handleColorChange(evt) {
  const target = evt.target;
  if (target) {
    if (
      target.classList.contains('label') ||
      (target.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'LABEL')
    ) {
      // evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
      // evt.stopPropagation();
      
      // prevent input field event delegation.
      evt.preventDefault();

      // prevents that a click on the label appears
      // to always set a red background color due to
      // handling this event twice once for the label
      // and a second time for the number input field.
    }
    const inputRoot = evt.target?.closest('label');
    if (inputRoot) {

      const inputNode =
        inputRoot.querySelector('[type="number"]');

      const inputStyle = inputNode?.style;  
      if (inputStyle) {

        const bgColor = (inputStyle.backgroundColor === 'seashell')
          ? 'red'
          : 'seashell';

        inputStyle.backgroundColor = bgColor;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log('evt.target ... ', target);
}
document
  .querySelector('form')
  .addEventListener('click' , handleColorChange/*, true*/);
```

```css
body { margin: -2px 0 0 0; }
label { padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px,}
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 140px!important; }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Time Settings</legend>
  
    <label>
      <span class="label">
        hours
      </span>
      <input name="hours" type="number" min="0" max="23" />
    </label>
  
    <label>
      <span class="label">
        minutes
      </span>
      <input name="minutes" type="number" min="0" max="59" />
    </label>
  
    <label>
      <span class="label">
        seconds
      </span>
      <input name="seconds" type="number" min="0" max="59" />
    </label>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @GeorgeTomeh ... I did add a second, this time event delegation based, code example to my answer in order to show the difference in between both techniques.

Comment: thank you for your addition. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to an event listener is the `Event` object, not the target of the event. Use `event.target` to get the element that was clicked.

```js
function changeColor(event) {
  let obj = event.target;
  if (obj.style.backgroundColor === 'seashell') {
    obj.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else {
    obj.style.backgroundColor = 'seashell';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if I need to pass more than parameter in changeColor function, how I will call it in the addEventListener.

Comment: Use an anonymous function: `addEventListener("click", function(event) { changeColor(event, "another parameter"); })`